# Active Cycle Touring Blogs

Tags: touring

I'm in the planning stages of a big US cycle trip and am doing some research into the best cycle touring blogs. I'm looking for active blogs of people or groups who are on the road and blogging along the way.

I'm already aware of [Vague Direction](http://www.vaguedirection.com) - which is awesome - but any others that have inspiring photos / videos?

Thanks!
Jonny

Comment: This might not be a great question for Stack Exchange specifically because blogs frequently become inactive. Check out: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask (That being said, I like PathLessPedaled.com.)

Answer (score 2):

[Crazy Guy on a Bike](http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/) sounds like just one blog but is actually many blogs with lots of touring information. The interface is kind of minimal like Craigslist but there is a lot of content there.

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.travellingtwo.com
- http://www.tomsbiketrip.com
- http://www.alastairhumphreys.com
- http://www.thatemilychappell.com
- http://www.weaveoftheride.com
- Although not on the road I love http://www.ridingthespine.org

A few examples

Comment: FYI- ridingthespine.org appears to be unreachable.

Comment: Don't forget that if you are promoting a site that you are affiliated with, you *must* declare your affiliation within the body of your post.

Answer (score 0):

I met this guy in Ecuador in 2011 and he's still going strong, almost at 50,000 miles.

http://theslowwayhome.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

The owner of [Richardson Bikemart](http://bikemart.com/) in TX is just now wrapping up a long tour. Here is their blog.

http://rhondaandjimstravel.blogspot.com/